# I want to reduce the decimal point length in the below code

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angularjs

In an HTML page, I want the output of my decimal numbers to have only two positions instead of three - Example: `13.16` and not `13.167`.

But it is not working when I try to set it. How can I do this using the code below?

```
currentJobStatus.push(
    cncActiveState[0].totaltime * 100 / 
    Number(stdcycletime[0].Standard_Cycle_Time)
).toFixed(1);
```

I have tried using `toFixed(1)` function, but it is not working.

Here is my node.js code :

```
currentJobStatus.push(
    cncActiveState[0].totaltime * 100 / 
    Number(stdcycletime[0].Standard_Cycle_Time)
).toFixed(1);
```

Here is my angular.js code:

```
<ngx-gauge 
    [type]="gaugeType" 
    value={{item.currentJobStatus}} 
    [thresholds]="thresholdConfig" 
    label="" 
    [append]="gaugeAppendText" 
    [thick]="8"  
    size="100"> 
</ngx-gauge>
```

`currentJobStatus` in the output is giving me `13.167`, but I only want `13.16`

Answer (score 2):

Try using type conversion...toFixed didn't work for strings.

```js
console.log(parseFloat(13.167).toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1.Take some variable
var foo;

Step 2.Assign calculation part to variable
foo=cncActiveState[0].totaltime * 100 / 
    Number(stdcycletime[0].Standard_Cycle_Time;

Step 3.Then use toFixed()method in the push()method.
currentJobStatus.push(foo.toFixed());